# Не получается написать POST запрос в Volley

Tags: android-volley

Странно. Во всех туториалах код такой

```
url = "http://httpbin.org/post";
StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, 
new Response.Listener<String>() 
{
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        // response
        Log.d("Response", response);
    }
}, 
new Response.ErrorListener() 
{
     @Override
     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
         // error
         Log.d("Error.Response", response);
   }
}
) {     
@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() 
{  
        Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();  
        params.put("name", "Alif");  
        params.put("domain", "http://itsalif.info");

        return params;  
}
};
queue.add(postRequest);
```

Но когда я пишу закрывающуюся скобку после `errorListener` компилер ругается

```
Missing ,
Unexcepted )
```

Вот мой код

```
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://pareto-marketing.ru/landlicense2.php?url=" + urlh + "&key=" + key + "&lastid",

    new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if(!response.endsWith("ключ")) {
                int serverId = Integer.parseInt(response.substring(1, response.length() -1));
                    int prefId = getLastPrefId();
                    if (prefId == 0) prefId = serverId;
                    if (serverId > prefId)
                    {
                        showNotification();
                        setLastPrefId(serverId);
                    }
                    else setLastPrefId(serverId);
                }
            }
        },

        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("$", error.getCause().toString());
            }
        }) //вот тут

    );
```

Comment: Скопипастил код с сайта выделялся `url` я заменил его на строку в итоге весь код подсветился

Comment: Помогите пожалуйста, я уже 6 ращ по разному пишу и ничего не получается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class PostRequest{
private RequestQueue mQueue;
private Map<String, String> params;
private String url;
public  String req;


public PostRequest(Context context, String url, Map<String, String> params) {
    this.params = params;
    this.url = url;
    mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context, new NukeSSLCerts());
    }

public void getString(final VolleyCallback callback) {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url ,
            new Response.Listener<String>(){
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    req = response;
                    callback.onSuccess(req);

                }
            }
            ,new Response.ErrorListener(){
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                        Log.d("VolleyError: " , error.getMessage());

                 }
    })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            return params;
        }
    };
    mQueue.add(stringRequest);
}


public interface VolleyCallback{
    void onSuccess(String req);
}
}
```

Я создал отдельный класс чтоб отсылать запросы, вызываю следующим образом:

```
final String[] payUrl = {null};
    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("foo", "bar");
    params.put("bar", "foo");


    PostRequest getPay = new PostRequest(this,url,params);
    getPay.getString(new PostRequest.VolleyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String req) {
            Log.d("reqInMainact", req);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Извините, я уже разобрался, просто вынес на мелкие части из этого громадного конструктора